# Stray CSS border-left

Tags: css

I have a unordered list styled in CSS to create a horizontal navigation.  Each list item has a border-left property to create a separator line.  The last item in the list does not have this border-left property (override by using border-left:0).  It works, however, the `<a>` link element (as opposed to the `<li>` element) is showing the border-left property.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove it.

Here is the web page in question:  http://sa4idev.com/stabilis/buy-lng-here/  -- if you look at the bottom navigation, you'll see "BUY LNG HERE" with a stray vertical border just to the left of the "BUY" -- it is not supposed to be there.  Any suggestions on how to remove that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that's actually coming from the background image `background:url('images/buy_lng_on.png') no-repeat;` applied to `#menu-item-59.current-menu-item a` (inspector said line 659). Double-check that the image doesn't have stray blue lines in it.

**EDIT:**

It's actually because you're putting the background image on *both* the `li` and the `a` inside it (and on `a:hover`, incidentally).  The blue line at the far left of the image is showing once for the `li` and once for the `a`.  Removing the background image from the `a` fixed the issue in my testing.

Comment: @Scott Check my edit. I think I've got it this time.

Comment: `@calvin:` That was it... the background image appeared twice and caused the blue line...

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS2 pseudo CSS selector.

in your case you want to remove border from the last li so you can do this by selecting `last-child` or if you want to remove border from the first `li` then you can choose `first-child` CSS selector.

```
li:first-child{border:0}
li:last-child{border:0}
```

Comment: If the solution work for you. please close this question by accepting the answer.  

Note: It would be good practice to post a code here for future reference for other users. just passing a website link not recommended.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `:first-child`/`:last-child` pseudo-classes are part of [CSS selectors level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors).

Comment: @HashemQolami sir you are right. I took reference from this site. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses. but I didn't go deep that's why made a mistake.

Comment: li:last-child{border:0} has the same effect as declaring border:0 for the specific li class in question.  And this does not solve the problem as the border-left appears to be associated with the `<a>` tag and setting border-left:0 to the `<a>` tag seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: `:first-child` is part of CSS2, but `:last-child` was deferred to level 3.

Comment: @BoltClock Interesting, I hadn't realized that.